# Changing sampling method for feature subset selection at nodes in randomForest R code

Tags: r, classification, regression, random-forest

I am working on the "randomForest" R package to change sampling method for feature subset selection at the nodes of trees in the forest. Currently random forest uses simple random sampling to do that. I tried to look at the R code by using the commands

library(randomForest)

getAnywhere(randomForest.default)

but could not find the relevant code chunk where "mtry" features are selected. How can I do this change in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried using the S3 and S4 methods described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function), but did not see all the functions in the `randomForest` package, and more important, did not see the `randomForest()` method listed.

However, if you navigate to the CRAN page for `randomForest`, you will see a link to the source code for the package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html

You can download a TAR file which has all the source code for the package from the above link.  The actual source code seems to be in the `code` folder, e.g. `rf.c` which looks like it might be the file you want to refactor.

Comment: Did you even try using the link I gave above?  I downloaded the entire source code for the `randomForest` package in less than 5 minutes.  I actually think my answer is the way to go if you want to do a serious refactor of the code, because it allows you to get a TAR containing everything.

Comment: Yes I have the source code including .c functions but could not locate it

Comment: Finding the file or files you need to change is really up to you, as we can't know exactly what you have in mind.

Comment: I want to refactor the chunk where a sub sample of variables are selected at nodes

Comment: To be honest with you, for you to reliably change the algorithm, you're going to need to understand how it works, at least at a fairly deep level.  So you might have to spend a little time reading through the source code.  This is not a waste of your time, because you'll probably learn a lot while doing it.